# How to use arraybuffer and typed arrays in js?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I have a lot of numbers between 0 and 255, and I would like to store them in an array. Uint8array would be the best, but I have no idea how to use it, and I can't find anything useful tutorials about it. And once they are stored in the array, how to modify/delete them, or add some new element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint8Array

Surprisingly, "[Uint8array javascript](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q=Uint8array%20javascript&oq=Uint8array%20javascript&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i8l2j0i8i10i30l3.1043.3447.0.3702.12.12.0.0.0.0.137.1035.9j3.12.0.les;..0.0...1c.1j2.K1Ckmv5xm2I)" has lots of interesting results about this.

Comment: thanks, but how to add/remove element?